# OpenCV hand detection?

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv, computer-vision

I have created a perfect skin detector, but it detects ALL skin. What are my possible options to separate the hands from the rest of the skin?

I don't want to use haar identifiers, so please don't suggest it.

Comment: Did you mean "hair", or is "haar" some kind of algorithm?

Comment: haar
its a type of machine recognition algorithim

Comment: How general do you need your detector to be? Will there be a (set of) particular gesture(s) to detect?

Comment: I just need to detect the actual hands
Im using convexity defects for gesture recognition

I am having problems with isolating the hands from the rest of the image, not detecting gestures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pretty sure that SIFT would work for this kind of thing, its much more powerful than haar.

take a look at this paper:
http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=sift%20hand%20recognition&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.103.4092%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&ei=sru5TtmSHurciAK6iJnyBA&usg=AFQjCNEsGRxKVLR1xIGSRT1XAQ2WPeehww

seems fairly straightforward

I'm been doing some SIFT as well, and my project plans does involve this type of thing, just that I haven't got to it. If you make some good progress, please be sure to fill me in.

Comment: Thanks for answering :)
Would SIFT require training with thousands of negative and positive images too though? Because I don't have the resources to do classifier training

Comment: @user1017485 you wouldn't need thousands for images just for hand gestures, but to get best results you do need to try to get images at every angle you care about. Since basically SIFT just gets all the interesting points on an image and you are basically matching those points to determine if the object is what you think it is. SIFT training is no where near as slow as Haar like features.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to first segment out the different skin regions through blob detection.

You can then eliminate the unwanted blobs by area and shape thresholding
A bit of filtering before these steps would help a lot

Comment: Thanks for answering :) Could you please be a little more specific though? As in how would I segment the different skin regions? Because histogram backprojection and colour segmentation don't exactly give precise results. Could you maybe please suggest a specific algorithm (i.e. the type of segmentation)